# Git ssh permission denied despite connection via ssh works

Tags: windows, git, ssh

My environment:

Windows host, CentOS guest with git Docker container (Debian based). User and password ssh authentication for git container is disabled - only ssh key authentication is allowed. I can successfully ssh from Windows to CentOS, from Windows to git container and from CentOS to git container.

ssh config file looks pretty much the same in Windows and CentOS:

```
Host git_name
  HostName <ip_address_of_CentOS>
  Port <port_mapped_to_container>
  User <git_username>
  IdentityFile <path_to_private_key>
```

This works perfectly fine from both Windows and CentOS (I can ssh into git container):

```
ssh git_name
```

When I try to git clone though with below command:

```
git clone ssh://git_name/example_path/repo_folder
```

repository is successfully cloned in CentOS but I receive below error from Windows:

```
Cloning into 'repo_folder'...
<successfully_resolved_user@ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Of course I checked for typos and I use the same <git_username> from Windows and CentOS. Repository exists as it can be cloned from CentOS.

I also tried below from Windows - the same result

```
git clone git_name:/example_path/repo_folder
```

What can be the reason why it works from CentOS and not from Windows?

Comment: Just to clarify that you do have ssh-agent running and your private keys added?

Comment: @ewokx yes, and as mentioned I can log in via ssh with "ssh git_name" without any issues

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: @Martingales Not a solution - rather a workaround. Git uses it's own ssh and it did not accept the key type. I added "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa" to my ssh config file and it worked.